# JEE: How to stop URL mapping?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, url-routing, httpsession

I'm trying to prevent URL mapping. Only logged in user will be allowed to assess `welcome.jsp` page.

My `Login.java` servlet is as follows,

```
package com.login;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
        String pass= request.getParameter("pass");

    if(uname.equals("indrajith") && pass.equals("123")) {
        HttpSession session =request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", uname);
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
    }
    else {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
    }


}
```

My `login.jsp` page contains following form,

```
    <form action="Login">
        Enter username:<input type="text" name="uname"><br>
        Enter password:<input type="password" name="pass"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    <form>
```

In my `welcome.jsp` page I'm checking what is the data user has entered,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    if(session.getAttribute("username")==null){
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
%>
    welcome ${username}

</body>
</html>
```

But my problem is still I can URL routing whether I'm logged in or not. I have no idea what is wrong with my code. In StackOverflow, there are some similar questions but the answers are not giving a solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance!

> PS: I'm using Tomcat 8.5.40 with eclipse IDE in my 64bit Windows machine.

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating your own security system instead of [standard JEE security](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbwk.html)?

Comment: No, the only reason is I don't know how to implement that security. I'm a novice to java ee

Comment: Isn't HTTPsession is a standerd way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you write in a `.jsp` will be added inside a method called `_jspService()` (long story short). After setting the redirect url, you must use the `return` statement to stop jvm from executing the rest of the code.

Keep in mind that `sendRedirect()` is just another method for jvm which adds the [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header in the response.

---

Update your `welcome.jsp`

```
<%
    if(session.getAttribute("username") == null){
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        return; // add this statement
    }
%>
```

and it's better to add this code fragment on top of the page.